# unplugin-icons: how to know the element name syntax?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying out this awesome project [vitesse-webext](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse-webext) and it comes with a lot of batteries included. One of which is [unplugin-icons](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-icons).

which allow usage of icon like `<pixelarticons-power />` in code like this:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useToggle } from '@vueuse/core'
import 'uno.css'

const [show, toggle] = useToggle(false)
</script>

<template>
  <div class="fixed right-0 bottom-0 m-5 z-100 flex items-end font-sans select-none leading-1em">
    <div
      class="bg-white text-gray-800 rounded-lg shadow w-max h-min"
      p="x-4 y-2"
      m="y-auto r-2"
      transition="opacity duration-300"
      :class="show ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'"
    >
      <h1 class="text-lg">
        Vitesse WebExt
      </h1>
      <SharedSubtitle />
    </div>
    <button
      class="flex w-10 h-10 rounded-full shadow cursor-pointer border-none"
      bg="teal-600 hover:teal-700"
      @click="toggle()"
    >
      <pixelarticons-power class="block m-auto text-white text-lg" />
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now I wanna now how I can change from Pixelarticons to ex. Fluent MDL2 (https://icones.netlify.app/collection/fluent-mdl2?s=hide).

I tried to do

```
<fluent-mdl2-hide class="block m-auto text-white text-lg" />
```

or

```
<fluentmdl2-hide class="block m-auto text-white text-lg" />
```

But are getting:

```bash
✓ 31 modules transformed.
[unplugin-icons] Could not load ~icons/fluent/hide (imported by src/contentScripts/views/App.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang.ts): Icon `fluent/hide` not found

build started...
✓ 16 modules transformed.
[unplugin-icons] Could not load ~icons/fluent/mdl2-hide (imported by src/contentScripts/views/App.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang.ts): Icon `fluent/mdl2-hide` not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured out how to solve it. In vite.config.ts I did:

```
plugins: [
    Vue(),
    ...
    // https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components
    Components({
      dirs: ['src/components'],
      // generate `components.d.ts` for ts support with Volar
      dts: 'src/components.d.ts',
      resolvers: [
        // auto import icons
        IconsResolver({
          prefix: false,
          enabledCollections: ['carbon', 'fluent-mdl2'],
        }),
      ],
    }),
```

so now I can do

```
<fluent-mdl2-hide class="block m-auto text-gray-800 text-lg" />
```

Just don't understand why Pixelarticons works out of the box (not specified in the `enabledCollections`)? ‍♂️